# Unable to connect to a specific Wifi programmatically on Android

Tags: android, wifi, wpa

I am trying to connect to a specific Wifi network (WPA2) on Android but somehow it is not working on a specific device running Android version 4.1.2. Whereas the same code is working on 2 other devices running Android versions 4.4.2 & 4.4.4. On the device it is not working, I see the network being added successfully because I can connect manually without entering the key explicitly. The code snippet is pasted below. Any idea if I am doing anything wrong here or is there a version dependency?

```
private boolean connectToWifi(String networkSSID, String networkPass) {

    networkSSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";

    WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager)(this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE));
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
    if(wifiInfo != null) {
        String name = wifiInfo.getSSID();
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(networkSSID)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    int networkId = -1;
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)(this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE));
    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
        if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals(networkSSID)) {
             break;
        }           
    }

    if(networkId == -1) {
        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = networkSSID;
        conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
        networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
        if(networkId == -1)
            return false;
    }

    boolean retval = false;
    list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
        if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals(networkSSID)) {
            this.addDebugMessage("Trying to connect to p2p network");
            wifiManager.disconnect();
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
            retval = wifiManager.reconnect();
            break;
        }           
    }
    return retval;
}
```

The necessary permissions are also added in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:required="true"/>
```